# Find two random variables X and Y such that P(X<Y)=2/3

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random-variables

The problem is in the title (sorry if that's not kosher) but I have absolutely no clue how to get started. What would be a good approach to take with this one? I don't believe I have even seen a $\Bbb P(X<Y)$ before!

Comment: What do you think P(X<Y) means?

Comment: The probability that one random variable is smaller than another? I don't really conceptually understand random variables in terms of their 'size'.

Comment: Do you know what random variables are? And how they relate to events?

Comment: Yes, $P(X<Y)$ is the probability that when considering an element $(x,y)$ in the sample space that $x<y$.  As for a hint, you can use incredibly simple random variables here... for example, $Y$ the random variable which is constantly equal to $1$.  You can now find an appropriate $X$ that pairs with it.

Comment: I understand what a random variable is; so is the problem asking to find $X$ and $Y$ such that the probability that any outcome $x$ from $X$ is less than any outcome $y$ from $Y$ is $\frac{2}{3}$?

Answer (score 1):

You are asked to find random variables $X,Y$ such that: $$P\left(\{\omega\in\Omega\mid X(\omega)<Y(\omega)\}\right)=\frac23$$

---

Hint:

Let $Y$ only take values in $\{0\}$ and let $X$ only take values in $\{-1,1\}$.

Then $\{X<Y\}=\{X=-1\}$.